# nano/vi open write protected file as a unauthorized user- Can I escalate to save?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, shell, vi

More times than I want to admit I will open a config as a non-super user and will go about making the changes I need. As soon as I save in nano, or vi I am met with permissions errors.

At this point I c/p foo my way around so I can close and reopen with `sudo`.

Is there a way to escalate to a super user in order to save without closing and reopening in vi or nano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about nano, but I do know that you can write a file you don't have permission to access in vim. Try running this command:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

This will save the file even if you don't have permission to it. [Nathan Long has a great explanation of how this works here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7078429/3524982), but I'll give a short explanation too.

`:w` doesn't mean *save*, it means *write*. So in this case, `:w !foo` means write into the external command *foo*. In this case, the external command is `sudo tee %`, where `%` is the name of the current file. Tee will write to a given file and STDOUT simultaneously, and since we run it with sudo, it has the necessary permissions to write the file.